# несколько вопросов насчёт получения доступа к идентификаторам и т.п

Tags: javascript

добрый вечер, во время написания одной функции всегда допускаю синтаксические ошибки (очень запутанная функция для меня ), хотя принцип алгоритма работы мне понятен , помогите правильно написать функцию .

Во первых хочу сказать что мне не ясно как можно взять элемент который например находится

```
<tr id=q3><td id=2>
```

попробовал таким образом выявить содержание, не получилось

```
console.log(q[3].z[2].innerText)
```

видимо по другому надо написать(вопрос первый: как правильно написать)

так , это таблица

имел такие  идентификаторы

```
var z=document.getElementById("z"+tdQuan)//идентификатор для td
var q=document.getElementById("q"+tdQuan)//идентификатор для tr
```

но немножко подумав стало ясно что верхняя запись ни к чему не годится , так как больше одного значения я не могу использовать , попробовал написать следующим образом

```
var td = new Array(tdQuan);
    for(var zz = 1 ; zz<=tdQuan; zz++){
    td[zz-1]= document.getElementById('z' + zz);
    }
    var tr = new Array(tdQuan);
    for(var xx = 1 ; xx<=tdQuan; xx++){
    td[xx-1]= document.getElementById('q' + xx);
    }
```

но не знаю правильна  ли это форма или нет

сама функция -

```
function proverka(){
    for (var k=0 ; k<tdQuan ; k++){
        if(td[zz][k].innerText=="X"){
            console.log("you win")}
else{console.log("you are lose")}

}
}
```

я не знаю является ли это запись правильным -td[zz][k].innerText

объясните пожалуйста если есть время

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для работы с таблицей все гораздо проще... находим таблицу по `id`, а дальше работаем с этим объектом напрямую **[смотреть инфу об этом тут](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_table.asp)** со свойствами **[rows](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/coll_table_rows.asp)**, **[cells](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/coll_table_cells.asp)** и т.д.

Как пример:

```js
function myFunction() {
   var x = document.getElementById("myTable").rows[0].cells.length;
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Found " + x + " cells in the first tr element.";  
}
```

```html
<p>Click the button to return the number of cells in the table's first row.</p>

<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td>cell 1</td>
    <td>cell 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>cell 3</td>
    <td>cell 4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

То есть, как видим, мы всего лишь нашли таблицу, а дальше уже работаем со строками и столбцами.

Всё это добро можно конечно проитерировать, пройтись в цикле

```js
function myFunction() {
  var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
    //iterate through rows
    //rows would be accessed using the "row" variable assigned in the for loop
    for (var j = 0, col; col = row.cells[j]; j++) {
      //iterate through columns
      
      //!!!!!!
      // вместо col.innerHTML можно писать col.firstChild.nodeValue
      console.log('td value: ' + col.innerHTML);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<p>Click the button to return the number of cells in the table's first row.</p>

<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td>cell 1</td>
    <td>cell 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>cell 3</td>
    <td>cell 4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Соответственно никаких идентификаторов более не требуется.

Comment: благодарю , я про свойства rows не знал

Comment: а в таблицах  разве используется метод value ?

Comment: @Тигран не понял сути вопроса.... вы берете либо внутренний html через `innerHTML` ... если из примера вопроса - то `col.innerHTML`  либо берете первый узел ячейки и непосредственно у него value..... опять же исходя из примера выше будет `col.firstChild.nodeValue`