# как в jQuery обращаться к columns

Tags: html, jquery

Ребят как получить значение колонок и выводить их в alert();
Помогите а то  мучаюсь и никак(((
Использую jQuery

```
<table class="employeeTable" border="1">
<thead>
<tr>
<th class="employeeTableHeader" scope="col">Name</th>
<th class="employeeTableHeader" scope="col">Department</th>
<th class="employeeTableHeader" scope="col">Age</th>
<th class="employeeTableHeader" scope="col">Salary</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr class="employeeTableOddRow">
<td>        
            John
 </td>
<td>
            Marketing
         </td>
<td>

            30
         </td>
<td>
            2000.0
         </td>
</tr>
<tr class="employeeTableEvenRow">
<td>        
            Robert
 </td>
<td>
            Marketing
         </td>
<td>

            35
         </td>
<td>
            3000.0
         </td>
</tr>
<tr class="employeeTableOddRow">
<td>        
            Mark
 </td>
<td>
            Sales
         </td>
<td>

            25
         </td>
<td>
            2500.0
         </td>
</tr>
<tr class="employeeTableEvenRow">
<td>        
            Chris
 </td>
<td>
            Marketing
         </td>
<td>

            33
         </td>
<td>
            2500.0
         </td>
</tr>
<tr class="employeeTableOddRow">
<td>        
            Peter
 </td>
<td>
            Customer Care
         </td>
<td>

            20
         </td>
<td>
            1500.0
         </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Спасибо и с Наступающим!

Comment: зачем вам для этого jquery? http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/557282/191482

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, наверное потому что для таких примитивных задач jq и придуман!

Comment: @Elena но ведь в случае с пробеганием по столбцам разницы нет.. и там и там цикл. количество рядов `rows.length` и всё. Тем более если это вообще единственная задача будет...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

например:

```js
$('td').each(function(){
  console.log($(this).html());
  alert($(this).html());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
  
<table class="employeeTable" border="1">
<thead>
<tr>
<th class="employeeTableHeader" scope="col">Name</th>
<th class="employeeTableHeader" scope="col">Department</th>
<th class="employeeTableHeader" scope="col">Age</th>
<th class="employeeTableHeader" scope="col">Salary</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr class="employeeTableOddRow">
<td>        
            John
 </td>
<td>
            Marketing
         </td>
<td>

            30
         </td>
<td>
            2000.0
         </td>
</tr>
<tr class="employeeTableEvenRow">
<td>        
            Robert
 </td>
<td>
            Marketing
         </td>
<td>

            35
         </td>
<td>
            3000.0
         </td>
</tr>
<tr class="employeeTableOddRow">
<td>        
            Mark
 </td>
<td>
            Sales
         </td>
<td>

            25
         </td>
<td>
            2500.0
         </td>
</tr>
<tr class="employeeTableEvenRow">
<td>        
            Chris
 </td>
<td>
            Marketing
         </td>
<td>

            33
         </td>
<td>
            2500.0
         </td>
</tr>
<tr class="employeeTableOddRow">
<td>        
            Peter
 </td>
<td>
            Customer Care
         </td>
<td>

            20
         </td>
<td>
            1500.0
         </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Елена спасибо Большое с Новым годом вас!

Comment: Желаю счастья Любви и всего хорошего от чистого сердца

Comment: @elik, Спасибо!!! И Вам всего наилучшего в новом году!!!