# Сумма ячеек таблицы JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Добрый день, есть вопрос, вот к примеру у меня есть таблица в HTML 4х4 с числовыми данными, и мне нужно на чистом JavaScript реализовать функцию, которая находит сумму ячеек в первом ряде таблицы и еще сумму всех ячеек таблицы
Возможно ли это, и как? Начальный код:

```js
function table() {
var num1 = document.getElementById("1").value;
var num2 = document.getElementById("2").value;
var num3 = document.getElementById("3").value;
var num4 = document.getElementById("4").value;
num1 = parseFloat(num1);
num2 = parseFloat(num2);
num3 = parseFloat(num3);
num4 = parseFloat(num4);
var summ = num1 + num2 + num3 + num4;
alert(summ);  
}
```

```html
<table border="3" id="mytab">
 <tr>
 <td id="1">10</td>
 <td id="2">10</td>
 <td id="3">10</td>
 <td id="4">10</td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
 <td>10</td>
 <td>10</td>
 <td>10</td>
 <td>10</td
 ></tr>

 <tr>
 <td>10</td>
 <td>10</td>
 <td>10</td>
 <td>10</td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
 <td>10</td>
 <td>10</td>
 <td>10</td>
 <td>10</td>
 </tr>
</table>
<br>
<input type="button" name="123" id="table" value="Suma" onclick="table()">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ссылаясь на [самого себя](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/557282/191482) как итерировать по таблице/строкам таблицы/ячейкам получается так:

```js
function myFunction() {
  // инициализация сумм (строки и общей)
  var rowSumm = 0;
  var totalSum = 0;
  // берем таблицу
  var table = document.getElementById("mytab");
  // итерирование по строкам    
  for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
    // обнуляем сумму по строке
    rowSumm = 0;
    // итерирование по столбцам      
    for (var j = 0, col; col = row.cells[j]; j++) {
      rowSumm += parseFloat(col.firstChild.nodeValue); // parseFloat(col.innerHTML);            
    }

    totalSum += rowSumm;

    console.log('сумма в строке: ' + rowSumm);
  }

  console.log('итоговая сумма: ' + totalSum);
}
```

```html
<table border="3" id="mytab">
  <tr>
    <td id="1">1</td>
    <td id="2">2</td>
    <td id="3">3</td>
    <td id="4">4</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>13</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>30</td>
    <td>40</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>10</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br>
<input type="button" name="123" id="table" value="Suma" onclick="myFunction()">
```

Comment: Да, все работает, спасибо большое, а то все советуют подобное на jquery писать

Comment: @DaveManston зависит от целей, от сложности проекта и от процентности использования jquery в проекте. Если везде используется jquery, то как сохранение консистентности лучше его использовать. Если всё на чистом js, то нефиг и jquery втягивать в это.

Comment: @DaveManston от галочки не откажусь :)

Comment: конечно, еще раз спасибо за помощь с:

Comment: а как модифицировать код, что бы считать сумму по колонкам, а не строкам?